# Send $_SERVER['PHP_SELF' with jquery to external php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In page included comment form.
With comment I want to write in mysql url from which the comment is posted.

The posted comment to php file will send with jquery, like `$.post("_record_comments.php", data_to_send_ajax_post, function(result_of_record) {`

To php file want to send current url (part of url)

Can create jquery variable like this

`var url = '<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>'`

or

`var url = '<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>'`

but from my knowledge anyone can set for `var url` any value, like `var url = 'wrong-url.html'`. In such case I would send incorrect url to php file.

How can prevent users to change value of `var url` and send to php correct url of current page?

Comment: you can't, Javascript being on the clients machine, you CANNOT TRUST anything that you get sent.  All you can do is validate and sanitise the data you receive.

Comment: You can't. And even if you could lock down the JavaScript, what prevents anyone from HTTP proxying the requests and modifying them any way they wish?

Comment: Any other options how to send correct url?

Comment: ok, if wrong url, then posted comment would not appear in website. Normal user would not change url. If a malicious user would change, I would write incorrect url in mysql. And a malicious user would not write comment that i want to display in website. So, seems i would leave all as it is

Answer (score 1):

To prevent random scripts from interacting with your script run all your code in your own scope:

```
(function () {
    var url = "";
}());
```

Now `url` is not accessible by anything else that might run in the global scope.

Note that this prevents changing of the `url` variable, but there are still plenty of ways a client can shoot himself in the foot and send the wrong request, but *why would they*? If there are security issues make sure you implement them first and foremost on the server.

Perhaps this is also worthwhile to mention: the JavaScript security model relies on the foundation that all code is *safe* to run. You (and your client) is in charge of what code runs on the page. If a third party can also run code you've got a problem. This is why it's so important to always encode your input, if an attacker can inject HTML it can inject an XSS script.

---

The correct way to encode variables in JavaScript is to use `json_encode`:

```
var url = <?php echo json_encode($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>;
```

`htmlspecialchars` is an encoding function used to print to an HTML context.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question as I can still change this variable and send the incorrect URL to the script.

Comment: :) thanks - in answer to the 'why would they' in this instance, it looks like he is sending a URL to be stored somewhere for calling upon later.. I could upload a URL to my XSS script, and then steal cookies from your visitors and hack the facebook and twitter accounts..

Comment: No that wouldn't work unless you can actually inject code. For XSS to work you need the value of `document.cookie` on the target domain. Simply redirecting to your own domain is not enough (unless of course the form sends you the value of `document.cookie` voluntarily, but that would be silly to begin with).

Comment: as cookies are stored in the browser and not in the JS, there are methods to get all the cookies in the current browser session.

Comment: Yes, but each domain has it's own session. If you visit _facebook.com_ it can **not** read cookies from _plus.google.com_. Unless _plus.google.com_ allows facebook to run a script on it's domain (because of the js-security model)